# Charging non USB-C laptops with USB-C charger - is it safe and will it work?

Tags: usb-c

I would like to know (1) if it is **safe** and (2) will it work to charge two old **non-USB-C** laptops using a USB-C charger.

My laptops:

1. Acer Aspire A515-54, which power supply provides output of 19V and 2.37A.
2. HP ProBook 445 G7, which power supply provides output of 19.5V and 2.31A.

My USB-C charger is a Lenovo, Max 65W, with outputs:
20V,3.25A / 15V,3A / 9V,2A / 5V,2A
(Model is ADLX65YLC3A)

I found online many USB-C to round-tip adapters on different sizes and shapes (e.g. [Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003153455116.html) which claims to output 19V with 4.74A), but I have no clue if it will safely charge the laptop (with no battery explosion or power supply damage etc).

Also, if I understand correctly, USB-C charging protocol starts with a handshake between the charger and device, to determine the correct power spec, so given that the laptops are non USB-C compatible (so no handshake happens), would power transfer even happen? Or is such adapters do the handshake themselves?

Thank you!

Comment: the charging protocol handshake should be happening between the power supply and the round-tip adapter ... not between the power supply and the laptop PC